# PhotoView - Get cell/touch coordinates relative to zoomed image

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

[image]

Basically, I added background image to Imageview and drawn some lines on bitmap. gSeed is the size of each cell. Now I calculated the index of each cell with Touch Listener. But as I am using photoView I am unable to use this following touch listener. Need help to use this function with photoview and on zoom it should give coordinates of imageView instead of screen because on Zoom it will show the original image cell details.

```
mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            float x = motionEvent.getX();
            float y = motionEvent.getY();

            String message = String.format("Coordinates: (%.2f,%.2f)",x,y);

            int Y = (int) Math.floor(x/gSeed);
            int X = (int) Math.floor(y/gSeed);

            int p = X*6+Y;;

            //gSeed values = no.of columns
            //200 = 6
            //190 = 6
            //180 = 6

            //170 = 7
            //160 = 7

            //150 = 8
            //140 = 8

            //130 = 9
            //120 = 9

            //110 = 10
            //100 = 11
            //90 = 12
            //80 = 14
            //70 = 16
            //60 = 18
            //50 = 22
            if(gSeed == 200 || gSeed == 190 || gSeed == 180){
                p = X*6+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 170 || gSeed == 160){
                p = X*7+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 150 || gSeed == 140){
                p = X*8+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 130 || gSeed == 120){
                p = X*9+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 110){
                p = X*10+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 100){
                p = X*11+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 90){
                p = X*12+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 80){
                p = X*14+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 70){
                p = X*16+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 60){
                p = X*18+Y;
            }
            else if(gSeed == 50){
                p = X*22+Y;
            }


            System.out.println(message+" Cell#/; "+ p);
            Toast.makeText(Train.this,message+" Cell#/; "+ p+" x:"+X+" y:"+Y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am running into the same

Comment: Yes, this particular task has been done but the project is still not completed. What is your main project? If same we can collaborate.

Comment: Please share how exactly you solved this @DaniyalTariq